# Can one use \XeTeXinterchartoks in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, xetex

Is the `\XeTeXinterchartoks` active also in math mode? I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \myletterclass 
\XeTeXcharclass `\a \myletterclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\A \myletterclass

\XeTeXinterchartoks \myletterclass \myletterclass {\hskip1em}

aAAaa          % ok

\textit{aAAaa} % ok 

$aAAaa$        % no

$\hbox{aAAaa}$ % ok

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to have the interchar tokens inserted in-between math mode characters?

[image: XeTeXinterchartoks not inserted in math mode]

Comment: Characters in math mode are processed as "mathchars" rather than "chars", so I guess that the interchar token feature is disabled.

Comment: So I guess my question should read 'is there an `\XeTeXintermathchartoks`?' and I suspect then the answer to be no.

Comment: You suspect right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is rather short, I'm afraid: no. The `\XeTeXinterchartoks` feature is disabled in math mode.